# How to show default tab when Resumed to activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity in which I have Tablayout and have two tab named as "Deal","Story" when I navigate to other activity and again resume to that activity
then that tab was appears which I had viewed earlier,while I want whenever I resumed to that activity always show default tab .How can I DO THAT

code:-

```
public void init() {
    s_oCloginSession = new CLoginSessionManagement(CMainActivity.this);// object creation of Login Session...
    setupToolbar();// setting toolbar

    // navigation bar code
    m_Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);//finding id of drawerlayout
    s_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, m_Drawer, m_Toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    m_Drawer.setDrawerListener(s_drawerToggle);
    m_Drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    s_drawerToggle.syncState();

    NavigationView m_Navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    m_Navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);// finding Id of tablayout
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Deals"));// add deal listin tab
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));// add stories tab
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab

    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    CDealMainListingPager m_oDealMainScreenPager = new CDealMainListingPager
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oDealMainScreenPager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: why you dont implement it in one activity and inherit from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one class named `BaseActivity` which extends `AppCompatActivity`. All your activity will now extend to this `BaseActivity` class instead of `AppCompatActivity`. So whenever you have not defined `onBackPressed` it will call it's parent class method and perform it's operations.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.translate, R.anim.left_to_right_simple);
}

}
```

> If you want to customise this method for one class then just need to override this method in that respective class. For other classes it will work same as defined in `BaseActivity`
>
> Your all activity will be something like this.

```
public class HomeScreen extends BaseActivity{
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a class, say `CommonMethods` and put the method into that class:

```
public class CommonMethods extends AppCompatActivity {

    /*This method functions when user press device back button*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((currentTime - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
            // Double Press
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lastPressTime = currentTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you can make this class extend `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` based on your needs.

Finally, you can make the activity classes which need this feature, extend this `CommonMethods` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by taking one common class and implement this function in it,

Check below code,

**Take one common class for method**

```
   //Here I am taking it as common class you can take it as per your choice
```

**CommonClass.java**

```
  public class CommonClass
  {
      public bool manageBackPressed(Activity activity, long lastPressTime)
      {
           long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if ((currentTime - lastPressTime) < 2000) {
                     return true;
             } else {
                  return false;
             }

            return false;
      }
  }
```

**Now below check your onBackPressed method in any activity**

```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

         if(commonClass.manageBackPressed(this, lastPressTime))
          {
               moveTaskToBack(true);
          }
          else
           {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 lastPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your previous thread will also work in background please cancel it when you dont want to update.